# I went to Canada to learn English vs I went to Canada for learning English

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Which one is correct and what is the diffrent between.

> I went to Canada to learn English

vs

> I went to Canada for learning English.

I heard the former is correct and the latter is wrong.
I just wanted to know about "for learning" meaning.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's really helpful to think in terms of "correct" or "wrong" in contexts like this, but the short answer is that almost all native speakers would use ***to learn*** rather than ***for learning*** in OP's specific case.

---

Here, for example, is a similar utterance where ***for*** [+ gerund] might be more likely...

> 1: *On Saturdays I often pick up a few beers **for watching** the football on TV on Sunday*.

The reason for this difference is that ***to*** [+ infinitive] more strongly implies ***in order to*** make the specified action or result **possible**. But ***for*** [+ gerund] can often imply a much weaker relationship (I *could* still watch the football even if I hadn't bought any beers the day before).

> 2: *I use these glasses **for reading** the paper.*
>    3: *I use these glasses **to read** the paper.*

I think most people would agree that #3 more strongly implies that *without* the glasses, I might not be able to read the paper at all. Where #2 might simply mean that's my most common reason for using those glasses, even if I can read reasonably comfortably without them.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. I guess your last paragraph is with some typo, e.g. #2 and #1, which might be #3 and #2

Comment: @WXJ96163: You're quite right. I can't actually remember, but maybe at the time I was thinking in terms of the **"first" + "second"** of my two "glasses" examples, and forgot that I'd already assigned **#1** to the single earlier example. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out.